# Distribution of a multivariate normal distribution transposed

Tags: probability, statistics

We have independent variables $Y_i$ that each follow a $N(B + A* Z_t ,\sigma^2)$ where the sum of $Z_t$ is equal to 0 and the sum of $Z_t$ squared is a constant c > 0.

What would be the distribution of $Y = (Y_1,Y_2,Y_3,..,Y_n)^T$  (the transposed joint distribution of all the $Y_i$'s)

**My attempt:** I'm thinking it follows a multivariate normal distribution of mean vector U that contains the different (B+A*Zt's) and it's variance is the identity matrix multiplied by a constant σ2. Not sure though

Comment: Welcome to MSE. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I'm thinking it follows a multivariate normal distribution of mean vector U that contains the different  (B+A*Zt's) and it's variance is the identity matrix multiplied by a constant σ2. Not sure though